# How to store and read precise datetime UserProperty in Outlook Add-In?

Tags: c#, datetime, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have that piece of code which creates a `UserProperty` in an Outlook `AppointmentItem`:

```
AppointmentItem copiedAppointmentItem = sourceAppointmentItem.ReferenceItem.CopyTo(calendar, OlAppointmentCopyOptions.olCreateAppointment);
copiedAppointmentItem.UserProperties.Add(SynchronizationTags.LAST_SYNCHRONIZATION_DATETIME, OlUserPropertyType.olDateTime, false).Value = DateTime.Now;
copiedAppointmentItem.Save();
```

If I add this piece of code just after the `copiedAppointmentItem.Save();` statement, `ls.Value` contains the exact time, including the seconds.

```
UserProperty ls = copiedAppointmentItem.UserProperties.Find(SynchronizationTags.LAST_SYNCHRONIZATION_DATETIME);
```

But if I then close Outlook, restart it and try to load the same `UserProperty`, it contains the saved datetime but without the seconds. For instance if I saved `2023/02/27 18:10:20`, I can only read `2023/02/27 18:10:00`. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook evaluates time according to that specified time format without seconds.

If you need to preserve the exact date time value you can convert the date time value to a string and then add a string user property (`OlUserPropertyType.olText`), not as a *date time*.

Answer (score 1):

Both Outlook UI and Outlook Object Model share the same code that forces truncation to the nearest minute, there is nothing you can do about that.

You can either store date/time values as strings (which can introduce its own problems when you perform conversion - you need to make sure it is not locale-specific and has enough precision for your purposes) or you can store the data as a blob - use either `DateTime.ToBinary` / `FromBinary` (or `FromFileTime`/`ToFileTime`) or convert a `DateTime` to COM-compatible `double` first and then use `DateTime.ToOADate` (and `FromOADate`) and convert to/from array using `BitConverter.ToDouble` / `FromDouble`.

Since `UserProperty` object does not support array type, your blob would need to be converted to/from a hex string (which is not locale specific and does not cause truncation).